# On shortest vector problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, lattices, euclidean-lattices

Assume we have an oracle which gives the length of the shortest vector in a lattice. Given this oracle can we find the shortest vector in polynomial time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. I'll write $\lambda_1(L) = \min_{l\in L\setminus \{0\}} \lVert l\rVert_2$.
I will also identify a lattice with any of its basis, e.g. I will write $\lambda_1(B)$ where $B$ is a lattice basis.

There are two relevant forms of SVP

1. **Search**: Given a lattice basis $B$, recover $\vec x$ such that $\lVert B\vec x\rVert_2 = \lambda_1(B)$ is the shortest vector in the lattice.
2. **Decision**: Given a lattice basis $B$ and length bound $t$, return "yes" if $\lambda_1(B) \leq t$, and "no" otherwise.

What you're asking for is implied by a reduction from the *search* SVP problem to the *decision* SVP problem, as your oracle can easily be used to solve decision SVP.
Such reductions are known to exist, see for example [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04138.pdf).